# How can a chip power up, recieve, send information with only 2 pins?

Tags: serial, communication

On my 3D printer(cube)'s cartridge there is a chip with only two pins. The 3D printer can through those 2 pins tell how much plastic it's left in the cartridge.

My question is: 
How can a chip power up, recieve, send information with only 2 pins?

Comment: The 1-Wire protcol does exactly what you describe. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-Wire

Comment: Too sad you gave this as a comment instead of an answer, would've given you "correct answer" D:

Comment: It's OK, it's not really an answer. A real answer would put more info here on 1-Wire, so that if someday Wikipedia ever dies, the information will be stored here. I figured by now someone else would have done it. I am lazy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to one wire, there is a possibility that the sensor isn't an IC at all, but some passive device. it could be some sort of strain gauge that weighs the filament if it rests on it, or so. I guess I'd have to see it :)

Answer (score 1):

The two means I'm aware of are either have the sensor use a capacitor to store some energy, and use the same wire to send both power and signals.

In [current loop systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Current_loop#Process-control_use) the sensor varies its resistance to signal to the controller.  For an analogue sensor, this can just be the effect of the sensor physics, but it also can be used for digital control, allowing many devices in series connected to a single wire loop running around a factory ( my first summer job was working for [Rotork](http://www.rotork.com/en/)'s industrial control division in the '80s on such systems ).

Another shared power and signal digital mechanism is '[one wire control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1-Wire)' where both master and slave use voltage signals. 'One wire' systems connect in parallel rather than in series, so require two wires to be run around the factory. (I suspect the name is a triumph of marketing over technical specificity).